# How do I COPY to a cstore_fdw table in Citus?

Tags: postgresql, columnstore, citus

I have configured cstore_fdw successfully on our CitusDB installation running on an Ubuntu server in AWS.

I tried to install the same on one of our client's servers running CentOS 6.5. I could install it but cannot execute `COPY` commands.

Is there any documentation on using `COPY` with cstore_fdw-based tables in Citus?

Answer (score 1):

CitusDB with cstore_fdw is supported, but CitusDB itself does not support `COPY`. Instead you can use the `\STAGE` command by following [these instructions](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/foreign-data#cstore-wrapper).

What's the specific error message you saw on Ubuntu vs. CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

Citus supports `COPY` command starting from 5.1 release. You could use it as the same manner you would use with regular tables. Please see Citus documentation on [bulk data loading](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v6.0/reference/append.html?highlight=copy#data-loading).